# Google charts haxis bug when single entry given

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am facing the bug (or feature) in the google charts where the chart displays date labels in hAxis in a weird way when there is only one or two entries. I found a demo on the web where the same bug exists:

https://blog.smalldo.gs/2013/04/google-chart-tools-walkthrough-part-3/#create-dashboard

To reproduce, narrow down the chart range slider unless only one entry is present on the chart. Instead of displaying date it only displays years with the step of 10 years. Is there any way to modify that or do any workaround so that the dates would be displayed correctly?

Comment: Where's your code? What did you already try?

Comment: @borracciaBlu my codes is nearly the same as in the given demo

Answer (score 1):

by default, the chart will create axis labels based on the data and size of the chart
when there is only one row of data, it's not sure what the axis range should be,
and adds year labels, to fill space at the bottom of the chart

to prevent this behavior, set `min` and `max` values for the `hAxis.viewWindow` option

in this scenario, the view window should change, every time the range filter changes

as such, disconnect the line chart from the dashboard
when the table chart's `'ready'` event fires,
use the filtered data table from the table chart to draw the line chart

you can use data table method `getColumnRange` to determine the `viewWindow`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls']
}).then(function () {
  var myData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  myData.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  myData.addColumn('number', 'Hours Worked');
  myData.addRows([
    [new Date(2014, 6, 12), 9],
    [new Date(2014, 6, 13), 8],
    [new Date(2014, 6, 14), 10],
    [new Date(2014, 6, 15), 8],
    [new Date(2014, 6, 16), 0]
  ]);

  var dash_container = document.getElementById('dashboard_div'),
    myDashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(dash_container);

  var myDateSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'control_div',
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'Date'
    }
  });

  var myTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType : 'Table',
    containerId : 'table_div'
  });
  google.visualization.events.addListener(myTable, 'ready', drawLine);

  var myLine = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType : 'LineChart',
    containerId : 'line_div'
  });

  myDashboard.bind(myDateSlider, myTable);
  myDashboard.draw(myData);

  function drawLine() {
    var dataTable = myTable.getDataTable();
    var dateRange = dataTable.getColumnRange(0);
    var xTicks = dataTable.getDistinctValues(0);
    myLine.setDataTable(dataTable);
    myLine.setOption('hAxis.ticks', xTicks);
    myLine.setOption('hAxis.viewWindow.min', dateRange.min);
    myLine.setOption('hAxis.viewWindow.max', dateRange.max);
    myLine.draw();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">
  <div id="control_div"></div>
  <div id="line_div"></div>
  <div id="table_div"></div>
</div>
```